# Elastic NEST using Term filter on text field with inner keyword field

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to do a Term filter on a text property accessing its inner keyword field following the new standard on Elastic 5.x...

I have a property like this one:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm running the below code to filter using the inner keyword field...

```
var searchResult = _elasticClient.Search<InvoiceResult>(x => x
 .Index("my_index")
 .Query(query => query
  .Term(term => term
   .Field(new Field("foo.keyword"))
   .Value("TEST")
  )
 )
);
```

Is there any way to achieve the same result using the model class? When I try the code below it never uses the keyword inner field.

```
var searchResult = _elasticClient.Search<InvoiceResult>(x => x
 .Index("my_index")
 .Query(query => query
  .Term(term => term
   .Field(field => field.Foo)
   .Value("TEST")
  )
 )
);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

NEST [has](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/property-inference.html#_appending_suffixes_to_a_lambda_expression_body) really handy extension method for this case.

```
var searchResult = _elasticClient.Search<InvoiceResult>(x => x
    .Index("my_index")
    .Query(query => query
        .Term(term => term
            .Field(field => field.Foo.Suffix("keyword"))
            .Value("TEST")
        )
    )
);
```

Hope that helps .

Comment: Thank you!  This took me a very long time to figure out for something I assumed would be trivial.